# Are absolute paths allowed in info files?

Tags: javascript, .info

I'm writing a `.info` file for a module, and I want to include a script which has been installed in `/sites/all/libraries`:

So I have included the line below in my `.info` file:

```
scripts[] = /sites/all/libraries/zeroclipboard-2.2.0/dist/ZeroClipboard.js
```

However, with or without the leading slash on this path, I always get the same result: Drupal treats this as relative to the module directory and tries and fails to load

```
/sites/all/modules/custom/clipboard//sites/all/libraries/zeroclipboard-2.2.0/dist/ZeroClipboard.js?nsnrjh
```

So maybe I've answered my own question, but I can't find any definitive answer to this in the Drupal docs?

Thanks all,

MB

Comment: BTW if anybody else is having the same issue, I've used `hook_init()` and `drupal_add_js()` to achieve what I needed: `/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 * Load the ZeroClipboard Javascript files at page load
 */
function clipboard_init() {
  drupal_add_js(libraries_get_path('zeroclipboard-2.2.0').'/dist/ZeroClipboard.js',
                                   array('group' => JS_LIBRARY,
                                         'every_page' => TRUE));

}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`_system_rebuild_module_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/_system_rebuild_module_data/7) is responsible for that. There is a whole section in code just to make sure:

```
// Prefix stylesheets and scripts with module path.
$path = dirname($module->uri);
if (isset($module->info ['stylesheets'])) {
  $module->info ['stylesheets'] = _system_info_add_path($module->info ['stylesheets'], $path);
}
if (isset($module->info ['scripts'])) {
  $module->info ['scripts'] = _system_info_add_path($module->info ['scripts'], $path);
}
```

My *guess* is that module should never assume that something exists if module itself does not install it. It's a way to introduce errors. Also, allowing modules to reach outside their directory might be a security breach.

If you need a script you can't include in your module, use [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries). Of course there are other ways, but most of them is problematic, and fixing all problems would pretty much result in cloning this ready module anyway.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd - **don't do this!** This code is quoted directly from Drupal source. It is taken from it letter by letter. Don't mess with it, that's simply stupid. If you disagree with Drupal's coding style, your choice, but you should **never** display this disagreement by code edits. Especially if code is quoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating custom module then you can use these function to add library or js file from lirary.

```
$info = libraries_load('ui.tabs');
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.tabs');
```